# Finish loading external js before loading body?

Tags: javascript, html, load

Is there a way to NOT load the body or anything else, until AFTER the external js in my head section finishes loading first?

EDIT DETAILS:
When my page loads, my button in the body appears right away. If I click it after waiting only a few seconds, nothing happens (the button calls a function in external js onclick).

However, if I wait several minutes before clicking the button, it works fine. I have nothing else in the body, but that single button.

I can't figure out how else to explain it, except the body must be loading before my external js finishes. Is there any other possible reason? Solution?

Comment: nothing needs to be done. It is the behavior of browser. HEAD runs before BODY.

Answer (score 2):

that is what the browser does now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [nice read](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch12_03.htm) I found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585979/are-external-scripts-in-the-head-of-an-html-document-guaranteed-to-execute-befor):

> The detail that is not so obvious, but is nevertheless important to
>   remember, is that execution of scripts occurs as part of the web
>   browser's `HTML` parsing process. Thus, if a script appears in the
>   `<head>` section of an HTML document, none of the `<body>` section of the
>   document has been defined yet. This means that the JavaScript objects
>   that represent the contents of the document body, such as Form and
>   Link, have not been created yet and cannot be manipulated by that
>   code.

Comment: Additionally you can link scripts in your page using `<script src="..." async>` or `<script src="..." defer>`. I believe they are not supported by _all_ modern browsers... [Read more about `async` and `defer`](http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/)